# Writable computed variables does not read value when copying same value twice

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events, knockout-validation

I am formatting a input into currency and using writable computed variables to update the value back to textbox.

e.g. I have a value 1234.12

I am copying the value from notepad and pasting it into the textbox, on tab out it is hitting the read function and getting formatted into currency and getting written back to textbox as $1,234.
When I am pasting same value 1234, its is not hitting the read, directly getting written as it is, in to the textbox as 1234 on tab out.

I have seen this problem in js also.

Do you have any idea how to format the value if I paste the same value multiple times.

Comment: copying the same value won't fire any change...however some code here would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `{ notify: "always" }` extender to ensure your data always gets formatted.

In the example below:

- The `_backingValue` contains `"1234"`
- When inputing `"1234"` in the `<input>`, the computed *writes* `"1234"` to the `_backingValue`
- Under normal conditions, the `_backingValue` would **not** notify any subscribers of a value change, since `"1234" === "1234`. *However*, because we explicitly told it to always trigger a `valueHasMutated` "event", it *does* notify its subscribers.
- `formattedValue`'s `read` property has a dependency on `_backingValue`.
- Because `_backingValue` notifies us it has changed, the formatting function will run again, outputting `"1234$"`.
- Under normal conditions, `formattedValue` would **not** notify any subscribers of a value change, since `"1234$" === "1234$"`. Again however, because of the extension, a `valueHasMutated` is triggered.
- The `<input>'s` value binding receives an update and renders `"1234$"` to the screen.

```js
const _backingValue = ko.observable("1234")
  .extend({ notify: "always" });

const formattedValue = ko.computed({
  read: () => _backingValue().replace(/\$/g, "") + "$",
  write: _backingValue
}).extend({ notify: "always" });


ko.applyBindings({ formattedValue });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="value: formattedValue">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped, and also its very generous of you to explain that stuff. Thanks a lot again